# Mutlires Modifier Unwantedly Increasing Detail?

Tags: modifiers, multiresolution

(Blender Alpha 2.90)

I have been working on a full dwarf character model and for some reason all the multirez data
that I have been saving is now suddenly "enchanced"? All the details on the character are now way more defined plus the general mass of of it has been "inflated" somehow? Its not fully a bad change since it has increadsed some of my deatails, but I am just super confused as to why and how this happene, since when I last worked on it I wasnt even sculpting and was working on a belt so I didnt even touch the mesh that had the multires modifier on it. The mesh wasnt even selectable so if I were to guess it might be something wrong with the modifier itself.

If anyone has experienced something similar I would really like to know so I can prevent it in the future or atleast just know what even happened. I have attached some images of what I am talking about with the first being the "before" and the last being the "after".

Any input would be appriciated.

[image]

[image]